# getExtent() in OpenLayers returns strange values

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

I'm trying to get the bounding box of the map area displayed by OpenLayers.

I tried to use map.getExtent() because it should be exactly what I need, but the returned values are "strange":

For example, if I center the map around Grenoble (France, 45.19 5.71) with zoom level 14, the getExtent returns : 634409.225396,5647894.800465,643008.391077,5652672.114732
I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. The getExtent() is supposed to return a bound object with Lat/Lon values...

The map is created with :

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
  displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

I'm using OSM as my base layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the coordinates are coming back in the map's projection (epsg 900913 AKA web mercator). You should be able to call [transform on your bounds object](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.transform) to convert it to lat/long. Try something like this (untested):

```
map.getExtent().transform(map.projection, map.displayProjection)
```

Comment: +1 - the displayProjection is only used by some controls that display coordinates